# In Emacs, can I have it show which open-paren it matches, without erasing/retyping the close-paren?

Tags: emacs

For example, suppose I have something like

```
(defn my-function []
  ..
  ..really long function body..
  ..)
```

When I scroll to the bottom and type the final `)`, the Emacs status bar says:

```
Matches (defn my-function []
```

which is super helpful.  But if I just cursor to after the final `)` (with `show-paren-mode`), it only highlights the opening paren, which is useless if it's scrolled off-screen.

Is there an easy way to get Emacs to show the "Matches ..." line without erasing and re-typing the final paren?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but -- if you haven't done so already, you may wish to take a look at the libraries of highlight-parentheses and rainbow-delimiters.  I made an unofficial custom modification to highlight-parentheses that permits scrolling off screen -- i.e., scrolling does not delete the highlighted parentheses overlays when using the modification:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25269210/2112489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the package `mic-paren` available from MELPA. It supercedes `show-paren-mode` so you can remove your existing configuration. After you install it calling `customize-group mic-paren-matching` allows you to customize it to your liking. The setting you want is `Paren Highlight OffScreen` which you should set to `t`. If you want to do the same from init file, the relevant elisp is

```
(paren-activate) ;; activates mic-paren
(setq paren-highlight-offscreen t)
```

`paren-activate` is an interactive command so you can call it from `M-x` as well. It activates `mic-paren` and deactivates `show-paren-mode`

Comment: Follow-up question: this works great (thank you!) if I run those two function calls by hand, after Emacs has started.  If I put them in my `.emacs`, though, it complains: "Symbol's function definition is void: paren-activate".  I've installed via MELPA (it's in ~/.emacs.d/elpa/mic-paren-3.8), and I see mic-paren has an autoload defined for `paren-activate`. Other autoloads in ~/.emacs.d/elpa/ seem to work fine.  Is there something I should do to load things in a different order?

Comment: Put a call to `(package-initialize)` before calling `(paren-activate)`. This will enable all the packages and their autoloads. Emacs automatically initializes all the packages after loading the init file, but here we are calling `mic-paren` before this happens. In general, you will need to do this for configuring any package during init itself.

Comment: There is also a [Emacs beta](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/) in Stack Exchange now. These would be ontopic and get more useful eyeballs there

Comment: Thanks!  That works.  And I'm going to check out the Emacs SE now.

Comment: Thank you! With show-paren-mode I could only get a brief 2 seconds offscreen parens description of match location by M-x toggling blink-matching-open, while with mic-paren the description display in the echo area is persistent and more informative as it shows the number of lines distance to the matching parens above. However, I still wonder if it's somehow possible to get this offscreen feature working with just show-paren-mode.